# Why am I getting error 35353 when enabling CDC on a table with a CCI?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, columnstore, change-data-capture

I'm trying to enable Change Data Capture on a table with a clustered columnstore index, a unique non-clustered index, and a non-unique non-clustered index in SQL Server Standard 2019. The command fails with this error:

```
Msg 35353, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_cdc_enable_table_internal, 
Line 243 [Batch Start Line 16]
Change Data Capture cannot be enabled on a table with a clustered columnstore index. 
Consider dropping clustered columnstore index
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error since, as far as I can tell from Microsoft documentation, CDC is supported for CCIs.

Has anyone else run into this error or know why it's occurring?

Answer (score 2):

I just heard back from Microsoft. The documentation on CCIs and CDC is incorrect/misleading. Change Data Capture is not supported for clustered columnstore indexes. It is supported for nonclustered columnstore indexes starting in SQL Server 2016. They are correcting the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

The workaround to this limitation is posted [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64368353/change-data-capture-cannot-be-enabled-on-a-table-with-a-clustered-columnstore-in):

1. Drop a clustered columnstore index if exists.
2. Enable CDC.
3. Create a clustered columnstore index.

Voila! It works!